# Why I receive "TypeError: doc is not a function" (Firebase 9, Firestore)

Tags: javascript, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I try to add a user in Firestore with a custom ID.

```
import { db } from "../firebase/config";
import {collection, addDoc, deleteDoc, updateDoc, doc, setDoc} from 'firebase/firestore'
 
export const useFirestore = (collections) => {

    const addDocumentUser = async (doc, id) => {
        try{
            const addedDocument = await setDoc(doc(db, collections, id), {...doc});
            return addedDocument.id
            
        }
        catch(err){
            console.log(err)
            dispatch({type: 'ERROR', payload: err})
        }
    }
    

    return {addDocumentUser}
}
```

When I run it I receive following error in the consol:

```
TypeError: doc is not a function
    at addDocumentUser (useFirestore.js:62:1)
    at useSignup.js:29:1
    at async signup (useSignup.js:23:1)
    at async handleSubmit (Signup.js:23:1)
```

What I am doing wrong?
I imported everything and the database access works for functions (addDoc) without the custom id.

Comment: db is what I created exported from a config file: const db = getFirestore(). This works for the other function with which I add documents in Firestore

Comment: That's not what I asked. Explain what the effect of following `doc` with `(db,` is intended to be.

Comment: I am not sure about this. I am new to react js and firebase. I try to practice and learn. I added the function how it was defined in the doc.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that you're redefining `doc`, so it has two definitions:

```
import { db } from "../firebase/config";
import {collection, addDoc, deleteDoc, updateDoc, doc, setDoc} from 'firebase/firestore'
                                                // 
 
export const useFirestore = (collections) => {

    const addDocumentUser = async (doc, id) => {
                                 // 
        try{
            const addedDocument = await setDoc(doc(db, collections, id), {...doc});
            ...
```

That second `doc` that I point out hides the function that you import before.

The solution is to use a different name:

```
import { db } from "../firebase/config";
import {collection, addDoc, deleteDoc, updateDoc, doc, setDoc} from 'firebase/firestore'
 
export const useFirestore = (collections) => {

    const addDocumentUser = async (data, id) => {
                                 // 
        try{
            const addedDocument = await setDoc(doc(db, collections, id), {...data});
                                                                           // 
            ...
```

Comment: Thank you very much!  Sorry, that you had to help me the second time. I appreciate it! I think after hours of learning today, I became blind for these mistakes.

Comment: No worries. This one is actually common, as `doc` is such a common name to use, and not necessarily easy to spot.